# Convert boolean to integer location in python

Tags: python

I have a boolean list, say:

```
x = [True, False, False, True]
```

How do you convert this list to integer locations, so that you get the result:

```
y = [1, 4]
```

?

Comment: Note that that's a `list` rather than an `array`: "array" has a different meaning to most Python users (and especially to NumPy users).

Comment: Given the R questions and Cross Validated activity in your profile, you'll probably be better served by an array than a list.

Comment: Yes, looks like it is, although I have to say @MarkDickinson 's answer is very clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension in combination with the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, for example:

```
>>> x = [True, False, False, True]
>>> [index for index, element in enumerate(x, start=1) if element]
[1, 4]
```

Alternatively, if you're willing to use NumPy and get a result of type `numpy.ndarray`, there's a NumPy function that (almost) does what you need: [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.where(x)
(array([0, 3]),)
>>> numpy.where(x)[0] + 1
array([1, 4])
```

The strange `[0]` in the line above is there because `numpy.where` always returns its results in a tuple: one element of the tuple for each dimension of the input array. Since in this case the input array is one-dimensional, we don't really care about the outer tuple structure, so we use the `[0]` indexing operation to pull out the actual array we need. The `+ 1` is there to get from Python / NumPy's standard 0-based indexing to the 1-based indexing that it looks as though you want here.

If you're working with large input data (and especially if the input list is already in the form of a NumPy array), the NumPy solution is likely to be significantly faster than the list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explaining why! There's quite a bit of info I need to take in. It's definitely a change from R, where you can just do `which(x)` and be done with!

Comment: @J4y: I guess `numpy.where` is kinda / sorta Python's answer to `which`. If you're coming from R, you almost certainly want to be looking at Python + NumPy rather than pure Python.

Answer (score 8):

Use `enumerate` within a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(x, 1) if j]
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple one-liner would be:

```
[i+1 for i in range(len(x)) if x[i]]
```